# javascript getting an array from an array in an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object `MyObject` and one of its properties `ItemIDs` is an array of ints. I want to get a new array `PageItemIDs` that contains only part of the ints. It's for a pager; I pass in the page number `PageNumber` and I get the IDs of the items on the page. Suppose the page size is 20 items.

This is what I tried. It doesn't work because js works with references so I end up changing the array of the object.

```js
PageItemIDs = MyObject.ItemsID;
PageItemIDs = PageItemIDs.splice(PageNumber * 20, 20);
```

And instead of getting the ItemIDs in the page, I end up with the ItemIDs not in the page.

I know I'm not that far off but if you can help that'd be nice.

Thanks.

Edit:

When I do

```
PageItemIDs = PageItemIDs.slice((PageNumber -1) * 20, 20);
```

it works for page 1 but for every other page, it returns an empty array.

Ok, I got it, nevermind.

```
 PageItemIDs = PageItemIDs.slice(PageNumber * 20, PageNumber * 20);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead of [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

`slice()` returns a slice of the array, `splice()` changes the contents of the array in-place.

Comment: ok, slice keeps the original array intact. However PageItemIDs.splice(PageNumber * 20, 20); with PageNumber = 1 returns the same array with all the elements, instead of page 1.

Comment: @frenchie, `slice()` works differently than `splice()`. `slice()` takes the begin and end of the portion you want to slice. `splice()` takes an index and a count.

Comment: PageItemIDs = PageItemIDs.slice(1 * 20, 20); returns array 0 elements.

Comment: @frenchie, of course, because you're asking for all elements between 20 and 20. If you want all elements between 20 and 40, use `slice(1 * 20, 40)` instead.

Comment: ok, I got it: PageItemIDs = PageItemIDs.splice(PageNumber * 20, PageNumber * 20);  Yes, I meant slice!

Answer (score 1):

```
PageItemIDs = cloneObject(MyObject).ItemsID;
PageItemIDs = PageItemIDs.splice(PageNumber * 20, 20);
```

Comment: Object #<Object> has no method 'cloneNode'

Comment: could you post how MyObject is defined please?

Comment: It's defined as an array of ints.

Comment: Thank you, this is really kind of you ;)

Comment: what the ... THANKS! That's what is happening when you don't double check your code! There is a tipo + functional mistake here, correcting it right now!!